# Possible to get resultset rowcount with query results?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Currently I need to run two queries to get both the total amount of items in my resultset as well as the resultset.  Is it possible to just get the resultset count as well as the resultset in one pass to the database.  I am trying to optimize my code so I don't have to make 2 passes to the database as these individual select statements already take minutes to run.  I am looking for a solution in both oracle sql and ms sql because I use both.  I am also using Microsoft's Oracle access libraries to get to the Oracle database and not the Oracle access libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property of OracleCommand or oracleDataReader that shows the fetched rows. The number of rows is known after fetchin all rows.

**But** if you fetch all data into an resultset, then you have the row count in `resultset.Tables[0].Rows.Count` as stated above. This has no extra costs on the database, because the Count is a property of the row collection. The index number depends on the amount of tables in your resultset.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Oracle version you can use the analytic function count( ) to return a column containing the number of total rows.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions032.htm#i82697

```
select a.*,
       count(*) over() totalRows
  from table1 a;
```

Comment: Good suggestion. But how would you read out the column using OracleDataReader? Using method GetInt32 actually throws an InvalidCastException.

Comment: It is just an additional column for the query (similar to just count(*)) so you would output it just like any other aliased numeric column.

Comment: Actually I figured out that it works when using `Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetDecimal(index))`

Answer (score 1):

OK this might be what you are after:
[@@ROWCOUNT](http://www.sqlhacks.com/index.php/Retrieve/Row_Count)

It returns the number of rows affected by the users last database operation. So you dont need to add a column or do another pass, just do the query then ask for @@ROWCOUNT:

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as 'Rows_Returned'

EDIT:

This only works for SQL server. For Oracle use SQL%Rowcount

Hope this helps

Comment: That's valid for SQL Server; the question is tagged for Oracle.  You'd use SQL%ROWCOUNT for Oracle...

Comment: Actually OP is after a SQL Server AND Oracle solution,

Answer (score 0):

If you are iterating through the result set, wouldn't it be possible to increment a counter in each iteration?

One tactic might be to add a column `count(*) as RESULTSET_SIZE`?

Comment: That was the only solution I could think of as well but I was wondering if there was a method I could use or some other strategy.  I'll tag this as the solution if there is no alternative solution that is better.